# Custom Google Cast MiniController

Tags: ios, chromecast

I have been tasked with customizing the miniController for google cast in iOS. I need to customize the mini controller's text color and also blur out the miniController
I have spend some time in trying to find sources that would help in this regard with no success. Could anyone please help point me to resources that will help me solve this or help inspire a solution?

I cannot post any sample code as this is for work.
FYI im new to iOS

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may refer with this documentation on how to [Apply Custom Styles to Your iOS App](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_styles). This procedure uses the example of setting the body text color of your app's mini controller to red.

1. Look in the [table of views and styles](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_styles#table_of_views_and_styles) to find the view name of the widget or group of widgets that you want to style. Group names are marked with ▼.

   Example: `miniController` widget view
2. Find the names of the attributes you want to change from the list of properties in the corresponding style class listed in this table.

   Example: [`bodyTextColor`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_u_i_style_attributes#ae3c7edb0c6afa66518322946299d23e6) is a property of the [`GCKUIStyleAttributesMiniController`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_u_i_style_attributes_mini_controller) class.

Sample code:

```
GCKUIStyle *castStyle = [GCKUIStyle.sharedInstance];
castStyle.castViews.mediaControl.miniController.bodyTextColor = [UIColor red];
// Assign colors, fonts and images to other properties, as needed
[castStyle applyStyle];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great stuff this is exactly what i was looking for.much appreciated.